# I want change the colors every 3 seconds on the page without refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the colors on the page change automatically every 3 seconds without refresh , like someone do refresh automatically every 3 seconds.
[image]

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Color Blocks</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body id="color">

<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#color div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function randomColor () {
  var  random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  return random;
}

var html = '';
var red;
var green;
var blue;
var rgbColor;

for ( i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++) {
    red = randomColor();
    green = randomColor();
    blue = randomColor();
    rgbColor = 'rgb(' + red + ',' + green + ',' + blue + ')';
    html += '<div style="background-color:' + rgbColor + '"></div>';
}

document.write(html);
```

Comment: have you tried setInterval() ?

Answer (score 0):

You could save a reference to every element and then update the color every 3 seconds with `setInterval()`

```js
function randomColor() {
  var  random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  return random;
}

function getRGBColor() {
  return `rgb(${randomColor()}, ${randomColor()}, ${randomColor()})`;
}

const elements = [];

for (i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++) {
  // Create new element
  const element = document.createElement("div");
  element.style.background = getRGBColor();
   
  // Save a reference to the element
  elements.push(element);
  
  // Add element to the DOM
  document.body.appendChild(element);
}

setInterval(function() {
  // Update the color of every element
  for(element of elements) {
    const rgbColor = `rgb(${randomColor()}, ${randomColor()}, ${randomColor()})`;
    element.style.background = getRGBColor();
  };
}, 3000); // Execute every 3000 milliseconds (3 seconds)
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: background-color 0.25s ease-in-out; /* makes color change smooth */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the line

```
html += '<div style="background-color:' + rgbColor + '"></div>';
```

to

```
html += '<div class="color-element" style="background-color:' + rgbColor + '"></div>';
```

so you will have an identifier

then create the following function

```
function changeColors {
    var colorElements = document.getElementsByClassName("color-element");
    for (i = 0; i < colorElements.length; i++) {
        var item = colorElements[i];
        red = randomColor();
        green = randomColor();
        blue = randomColor();
        rgbColor = 'rgb(' + red + ',' + green + ',' + blue + ')';
        item.style.backgroundColor = rgbColor;
    }
}
```

now to make it so the function is run every 3 seconds like this

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    changeColors();
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Nico - Schulz , it's working perfectly , but I didn't understand the logic behind the code

Comment: Well you first use your code to create the elements and give them their first color. Then in the changeColor function I get all elements that have the class "color-element" witch I told you to put on the elements. then I loop trough all the elements with the for loop. For every element we generate a new random color and that to the already existing element. And with the SetInterval function we make sure it is run every 3 seconds (3000 ms) I hope this helps :) If you have a specific question about a part of my code I might be of better help

Answer (score 0):

I would consider a CSS animation with a filter to change the colors:

```js
function randomColor() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  return random;
}

var html = '';
var red;
var green;
var blue;
var rgbColor;

for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  red = randomColor();
  green = randomColor();
  blue = randomColor();
  rgbColor = 'rgb(' + red + ',' + green + ',' + blue + ')';
  html += '<div class="box" style="background-color:' + rgbColor + '"></div>';
}

document.write(html);
```

```css
div.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
  animation:change 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes change{
  0%,33% {
     filter:hue-rotate(0);
  }
  34%,66% {
     filter:hue-rotate(60deg);
  }
  67%,100% {
     filter:hue-rotate(120deg);
  }
}
```